# Adding dynamic variables to html content using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some html templates saved in MySQL database and I need to mix the retrieved html template with some variables, But when I do that I get the variable name printed instead of it's value.
How can I solve this issue ??

Comment: Not a good approach to write php code in db and try to execute that, try string replacements.. https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_regex_preg_replace.asp

Comment: Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I used str_replace function and it worked fine for me.
Thanks